# Spring AMQP is there a way to set the maximum number of consumers across all VMs?

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have 4 instances of my spring boot app running on 4 different JVMs.  Is there a way to set maximum global consumers?  Currently I have  setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1); set.  The problem is that there is one consumer being created on each JVM.  I was hoping to have one consumer created across the 4 JVMs.  I am currently using SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory and was hoping that this feature is available there.  If not is this possible with DirectRabbitListenerContainerFactory?

Basically I think I am asking how to set channel.basicQos(15, true);  // Per channel limit in Spring-AMQP for RabbitMQ.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set such a limit if that limit is greater than 1.

To limit to a single consumer you can set the consumer's exclusive flag (on the `@RabbitListener`); then only one consumer is allowed and the other instances will keep trying to consume until the current consumer dies (warm standby).

Comment: Using the exclusive flag on the RabbitListener works, however my other consumers keep trying and logging a message saying there is another consumer who has an exclusive lock.  Is there a way I can change the interval at which the consumers re-try the queue?

Comment: According to spring documentation it looks like I need to change the recoveryInterval.  I am still looking where to change this value.

Comment: I found recoveryInterval on the SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.

Comment: Also see `setExclusiveConsumerExceptionLogger()` whereby you can change the level at which the failure to consume from exclusive queue exceptions are logged (default WARN). The setter is not available on the container factory but you can set it on the container by getting a reference to it using the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` (just cast it to `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` to set the property). The default implementation is `AbstractMessageListenerContainer.DefaultExclusiveConsumerLogger`.